# How to access lateinit variable from companion object in SprintBoot test in kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, testing, kotlin, spring-boot-test

I have a test class like following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class UserControllerTest{
    @Qualifier("userRepository")
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @AfterClass
        @Throws(Exception::class)
        fun cleanupAll() {
        }
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun testUserShouldBeCreated() {
//        Some Test
    }
}
```

How do I access `userRepository` from `cleanupAll` method?

I have tried with:

```
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @AfterClass
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun cleanupAll() {
        UserControllerTest().userRepository.deleteAll()
    }
}
```

It gives the error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property userRepository has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem actually has nothing to do with `lateinit`.

Your `cleanupAll` creates a *new* `UserControllerTest`. So it wouldn't do anything with the `UserRepository` used in the test even if it worked.

For this specific case, if a single `userRepository` should be shared between all tests, it should be declared in the companion object as well; if it shouldn't, then the cleanup method should be in the class, not the companion object.